# Server is timing out because of Sunspot-Solr reindex'ing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, sunspot, sunspot-solr, reindex

Not too sure how to debug this. Any tips would be *greatly* appreciated.

Basically, I just did a large commit, and now my server can't boot up because of a Sunspot-solr issue.

I notice it when I try to manually reindex.

This is the return :

```
Processing MainController#index (for 69.114.195.64 at 2011-08-02 06:47:21) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"main"}
  HomepageBackground Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `homepage_backgrounds` 
  HomepageBackground Columns (23.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `homepage_backgrounds`
  HomepageBackground Load (0.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `homepage_backgrounds` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
  SQL (30.2ms)   SHOW TABLES
  Organization Columns (1.8ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `organizations`
  Solr Select (Error)   {:q=>"*:*", :start=>0, :fq=>["type:Organization", "published_b:true", "updated_at_d:[2010\\-08\\-02T13\\:47\\:21Z TO *]"], :rows=>1000000}

Timeout::Error (execution expired):
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `rbuf_fill'
  vendor/gems/right_http_connection-1.2.4/lib/net_fix.rb:51:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I reverted and rebased to the last working commit. And I still got the same error. So then I `ps aux | grep solr`, and found five instances of solr running. Strange, I thought, and killed every single one of them. Blam server was back up and running strong. So now I'm trying my new commits again, but with my eye on these feral sunspot instances.

Comment: Try optimizing your index with **Sunspot.optimize**.

Comment: That literally is just telling me to perform the same thing that erroring

Comment: Did you run it? What was the output?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by feral sunspot-solr instances running amuck. Nothing kill -9 couldn't handle. Problem solved.